# getting zero passing double android

Tags: android

I'm wondering why do I get zero in my list after I pass double `t` to method `getListe();`?

I want my program to print input values to the list, but when I'm adding I'm getting zero as result, I have defined double in`onCreate` method but I don't think it's used..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements BasicDialogFragment.OnNameEnteredListener {
    public static final String P1 = "melding";

    double l;
    double t;
    private static final String[] VERDIER =
                              {"Serielån", "Annuitetslån"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //input        = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.skrivTekst);
        listeKnapp   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.liste_button);
        final EditText laan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.laanInput);
        final EditText aar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aarInput);
        final EditText termin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.terminInput);
        final EditText rente = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.renteInput);
        final Spinner valgSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        double t = Double.parseDouble(termin.getText().toString());

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, VERDIER
        );
        valgSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);



        listeKnapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                visListe();
            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getListe(){

        String[] listeTabell = new String[50];
        for(int rad=0;rad<listeTabell.length;rad++) {
            listeTabell[rad] = "Dette er rad nr. " + rad + " " + 10 + " " + t;

        }
        return listeTabell;
    }
    private void visListe() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListeDemo.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("no.hit.jon.liste", getListe());
        i.putExtra("no.hit.jon.listeBundle", b);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `0` since you are declaring `t` as a global class member, but never use it.

Try adding this to your `getListe()` method

```
private String[] getListe(){

    double t = Double.parseDouble(termin.getText().toString()); //Add this line

    String[] listeTabell = new String[50];
    for(int rad=0;rad<listeTabell.length;rad++) {
        listeTabell[rad] = "Dette er rad nr. " + rad + " " + 10 + " " + t;

    }
    return listeTabell;
}
```

Comment: it worked but how do i get to subtract from LB every time if i say its 1000 - 100 so next time it would be 900 - 100 ?

Comment: What is `LB`? What do you mean by `subtract from LB every time`? @BaltušauskaitėKristina

Comment: LB  is total amount, yes subtract from it every time :))

Comment: if LB 1000 first time u get 900 and next 800 and so on

Comment: You have to be more specific. It also seems that you have modified your code in `getListe()`. You should make an edit to your question, adding the current code but do not modify your original code because it will take my answer out of context. @BaltušauskaitėKristina